# Database-Table for several clients

Tags: php, mysqli

i have a product table for a shop system that is used by several clients.
each client has its own users and the users of client a should see only the products of client a.
So client a sents his csv-file in a ftpaccount and client b sents his csv-files to another ftp account.

the product-table contains a field "client" that identifys the products of client a,b ...

a cronjob running on the server starts a script to import the csv-files.
If client a has sent data the script deletes the products from client a and imports them newly.
Then the script goes to the next client.

Now i want to prevent an empty product table during the import for the clients.

my idea :
create a copy of table "products" -> "products_import".
delete the rows for the client and import them there.
At the end rename "products_import" to "products".

Are there other ideas or ways to do that ?

Comment: You should do the import inside a transaction - changes to table PRODUCTS won't be visible to other transactions until you run COMMIT.

Comment: There are plenty ways to go on this. Yours would work. The already suggested transaction is probably very clean. One other way would be to flag them with "active" and deactive/activate them in one query (which should also happen in a transaction but would make the lock time way lower than doing the whole thing in one transaction, depending on size)

Comment: can you be a little more specific how this would work with transations. i have never done this.